# How to know if a given DLL is loaded by a given process?

Tags: c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically get DLL dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450039/how-to-programmatically-get-dll-dependencies)

On Windows, in a C++ program, I want to know if a given DLL (I know the path) is loaded by a given external process (I know the path of the exe), using win32 functions.
It must be possible to list all DLLs loaded by a process, as process explorer does.

Fabien

Comment: Isnt it almost similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450039/how-to-programmatically-get-dll-dependencies

Comment: 450039 talks about static analysis this one about dyanmic, but the answer at 450039 is for both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have get the ID of the Process you are looking for. Use the EnumProcesses function described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find your desired process. There is a nice [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623%28VS.85%29.aspx) provided to list all processes and their names, that you can use as a starting point.

As the second step you can list all of the modules, that is the DLLs loaded by each process.
Use the [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

[This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682621%28VS.85%29.aspx) does mostly what you want, you only need to add some more check code to filter for your process and your module.