# DLLs for current process

Tags: c++, windows, dll, process

how can one tell (using non-CLR C++) which DLLs is a given running process (by ID) using? With file system paths to those DLLs and EXE.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: POssible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450039/how-to-programmatically-get-dll-dependencies

Comment: @Anton: Loaded modules are different from dependencies, and that other question is .NET-focused.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I said about duplicates according to accepted answer in that question. The answer covers EnumProcessModules function, which return 'runtime process dependencies' or all modules loaded in process. I just reread that question and it about static dependencies indeed, so you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Anton: You do have a point that even though the other question isn't exactly a dupe, the answer covers this question as well.

Comment: @Ben: Yes! It's strange but these different questions have same answer. Actually that answer is not answer for that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in code, you are probably looking for the [`EnumProcessModules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682631.aspx) function (or `K32EnumProcessModules` depending on operating system. See the link for more details). There is an `EnumProcessModulesEx` that can give you a little more more information. Simply give it a handle to the process you want to know which modules (DLLs) are loaded. If you don't know the handle, you can find it using `EnumProcesses` or `OpenProcess` if you know the PID.

Comment: Here you can find sample code which demonstrates approach with `EnumProcessModules` function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682621%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: This question is explicitly for the current process, there's got to be a better p

Comment: @DitmarWendt this answer will work for other processes, too (as I already said in my answer). EnumProcessModules takes a handle to any process you want to enumerate.