# Find dependent modules of dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I have my own custom.dll (C++, Windows) library which depends on : zlib.dll, iconv.dll, etc.
The custom.dll is loaded by custom.exe.

Is there way in C++/WinAPI to find list of modules custom.dll depends in runtime?

There is function EnumProcessModules which works for process.

Is there something for dynamic library loaded by process?
As sample, the dependecy walker utility, fileInfo plugin display this information properly.

Comment: Have a look at [Programmically finding the dependencies (C#)] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450039/how-to-programmatically-get-dll-dependencies. This qn. is for C#, but there are some useful links in the answer.

Comment: Sure, use EnumProcessModules().  Twice, before and after you LoadLibrary() the DLL.  The difference is presumably what you're interested in.  Very hard to see the point of doing this btw.

Comment: @HansPassant: That misses shared dependencies. E.g. `Kernel32.DLL` won't show up.

Comment: Are you familiar with the different types of dependencies? E.g. delay-loaded DLL's ?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at dependency walker.  It does exactly what you're asking for.  http://www.dependencywalker.com

Comment: Denis Solovov ask for runtime solution, but +1, this is really cool utility, I used it for several years.

Comment: Are you trying to find dynamic loads?  eg: LoadLibrary?  depends does that...  Otherwise, I didn't read thoroughly...